# Responsive submenu

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a responsive menu but I'm not getting responsive dropdown in SERVIÇOS.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I'm two days working on it and I'm already tired of it.

menu.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function curPageName() {
     return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
    }   
    echo '<nav class="top-nav"><ul class="top-nav">';
    if(curPageName() == 'index') {
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'quemsomos.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'servicos.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'experience.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'massagem.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'social.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'tecno.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'clientes.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'contato.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'administracao.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
    } elseif(curPageName() == 'login.php') {
        echo '<li class=""><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="login">Login <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                     echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/administracao"> ';
                }
    } else {

        echo '<li class="active"><a href="index">Início <span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="quemsomos">Sobre nós<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="servicos">Serviços<span> </span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="clientes">Clientes<span> </span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="contato">Contato <span> </span></a></li>';
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                    echo '<li class=""><a href="administracao">Administração <span></span></a><small><a href="logout">(Logout)</a></small></li>';
                }
    }
    echo '</ul><a href="#" id="pull"><img src="images/nav-icon.png" title="menu" /></a></nav>';
?>
```

This part is not getting responsive and I do not know what else I can do.

```
<ul> //This is not getting responsive
    <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="massagem">Massagem</a></li>
    <li><a href="social">Social</a></li>
    <li><a href="tecno">tecno</a></li>
</ul>
```

bootstrap.css

```
 .nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: none;
}





.nav > li > ul > li{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.nav > li > ul > li > a{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.nav > li > ul > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: make it more specific and if possible, create a fiddle rather than outputting code

Comment: May or may not help you in troubleshooting, but as a word of advice... when you're echoing huge blocks of code, I generally find it's more beneficial to use heredocs instead, and find problems are easier to troubleshoot if you do so. Many IDEs (such as phpstorm if you name them appropriately, such as a heredoc named HTML) will even do syntax highlighting of the heredoc.